# they are known or known

Tags: grammar

I don't understand this sentence well and am not sure where the subject is so I don't know what I can fill.

1. At present production levels, **they are known** deposits of bauxite can provide the world with aluminum for hundreds of years.
2. At present production levels, **known** deposits of bauxite can provide the world with aluminum for hundreds of years.

I think the first sentence (they are known)is correct but I saw the answer key is the second sentence (known).

Comment: The first sentence is ungrammatical.  The sentence reduces to:  deposits can provide for years.  Thus anything the precedes *deposits* must be adjectival.

Comment: Jim I think it reduces to "Deposits can provide the world" - *the world* is an argument [DO], *for years* is an adjunct. Without the *with* it would be "Deposits can provide the world aluminum" - *the world* is IO, *aluminum* is DO.

Comment: Yes, of course you are right. Thanks. But the adjectival prescription is still correct I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first example is incorrect, and the second is correct.

In the second clause, the subject is "known deposits of bauxite" and the predicate is "can provide the world with aluminum...".

An alternate wording would be

> At present production levels, *there are* known deposits of bauxite *that* can provide the world with aluminum for years to come.

*There* can be used as a kind of "dummy" subject here, when there is no actual subject to the clause.

*They* can not be substituted here. To use *they* you would have to have some context that establishes what *they* refers to:

> Jamaica has many bauxite deposits. *They are* enough to supply to world for many years to come.

Here *they* refers to the specific bauxite deposits in Jamaica that were previously mentioned.

Comment: I think the wording I would choose is:  *At present production levels, **the** known deposits of bauxite can provide ...*

Comment: @Jim, I can't say that's not grammatical, but I wouldn't write it. If I wanted to use *the* I might write, "...the bauxite deposits that we know..."

Comment: The difference is subtle, but using *there are known deposits* implies that there exist, among all known deposits, some deposits which by themselves can provide the world..., while saying *the known deposits* means that taken together all the known deposits can provide...

Comment: @Jim, If all of the known deposits can supply the world with aluminum, then surely 1 fewer deposits than that could also do so.

Comment: If I've got 10 dimes I can buy a candy bar that costs a $1.  Surely I could also buy it with only 9 dimes, right?

Comment: @Jim, I believe the number of known deposits of bauxite in the world is not a small number like 10. I think it's actually a number so large that it couldn't be counted to produce an exact number. And if you're rounding of your count to the nearest 1000 deposits or so, then leaving out the smallest of them from your count is unlikely to affect how many years worth of aluminum those deposits could supply.

Comment: More to the point, in this context bauxite deposits are, to me, grammatically a mass noun rather than a count noun. You never talk about 10 or 20 or 2000 deposits of bauxite, you just talk about bauxite deposits (in general or in a given country or region) containing so many 1000s of tons of ore or whatever.